# Can I limit specific characters in a SQL Server column? Will it improve size and query speed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I couldn't figure out the correct terminology for what I am asking so I apologize if this is in the wrong place or format.

I am rebuilding a database, call it `aspsessionsv2`. It consists of a single table with over 11 billion rows. Column 1 is a string and has no limits other than under 20 characters. The other columns all contain HEX data... so there isn't any reason for that field to store characters outside of A-F and 0-9.  So...

1. Is there a way I can configure SQL Server to limit the field to those characters?
2. Will that reduce the overall size of the database?
3. Will that speed up queries to a database of this size?

What got me to thinking about this was WinRAR. I compressed a 50GB file containing only HEX characters down to 206MB. That blows my mind even though I understand how it works so I am curious if I can do the same "compression" in a way on a SQL Server database.

Thank you!

Been a little bit since I have asked a question. Here is some tech info: Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008, 10 Columns, 11 Billion Rows

Comment: Posting actual "CREATE TABLE" for your table may clarify what you mean "HEX data" (as there is no such type in SQL to my knowledge).

Comment: Have you tried the (var)binary datatype?

Comment: I am testing all three tomorrow but the varbinary sounds very promising!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `blob` (binary large object), that would cut the size of the hexadecimal-data fields in half. Often hexadecimal encoding is used to circumvent character encoding issues.

You could also use a Base-64 encoding rather than a base-16 (hexadecimal) encoding; it would use 6 bits per character rather than 4, and only increase the storage relative to a blob 4:3 times, instead of increasing it 2-fold in the case of hexadecimal strings.

Comment: On my first test this increased the size of the database by 33%. I think it may be my fault though. When I import the data I told it the output character limit was 32. Maybe that caused some extra fluff after the conversion? When I look at the table now I see 0xDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF00000000000000000000000000000000 instead of just DFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF

Comment: I should also mention that I encoded DFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF into a Base-64 string and it became longer than the 32 characters.

Comment: You first *decode* it, of course, so it becomes 16 bytes. Then encode it, and it will become around 21 to 22 characters. Encoding into Base64 will always add about 33% size, and encoding to Base16 will always double the size (add 100%).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `varchar` or `nvarchar` to store strings of characters 0-9 and A-F, then you should really be using [`varbinary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188362.aspx) type instead. Each pair of hexadecimal characters represent one byte, so with `varbinary` each byte of data needs 1 byte on disk, with `varchar` each byte of data needs 2 bytes on disk, with `nvarchar` each byte of data needs 4 bytes on disk.

Having `varbinary` instead of `varchar` will reduce the overall size of the database and it will speed up queries, because less bytes need to be read from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Hex values are just numbers so you are likely better off storing them as such. For example `123abc` would convert nicely to `1194684` and would only require 4 bytes instead of 8 bytes (6 characters + 2 byte `varchar` overhead). So provided the number isn't going to go above `2147483647` you can store them all as `int`.

However, if you wanted to restrict the column to only containing the values `0-9` and `a-f`, then you could use a `check constraint`, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_YourTable_YourColumn CHECK (YourColumn NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%')
```

Comment: So I was hopeful for this to work... and decided to try testing the hex into decimal and found that even half of the characters (16) equals a number over 16 characters long and way over 2147483647. So that would either fail or increase the size I think.

Comment: Well you can use `bigint` instead of `int`, that goes all the way to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and is 8 bytes.